# How to change direction of boulder

Tags: dungeon-keeper-2

In Dungeon Keeper II, I encountered a bonus mission, where I'm asked to 'guide' boulders from boulder traps to squash dwarves around the map. I have tried to slap them as [suggested in DK wiki](http://dungeonkeeper.wikia.com/wiki/Boulder_Trap), but I can't see any effect.

What exactly determines the direction of a boulder when I slap it?

Comment: If I recall correctly, slapping something (including boulders) makes it move away from the camera. I don't have DK2 on hand right now to check, though.

Comment: My tests had confirmed this, though sometimes to boulder disobeys. Unfortunatelly, I can't get to complete the level - the camera does not rotate fast enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both the original Dungeon Keeper and the sequel, slapping something sends it flying away from the camera. Boulders will continue moving in that direction until something forces them to turn again.